# Error when using conio.h to change text colour

Tags: c++, text, colors

Hey just found a library i want to use called coni.h to change text colour.  But im getting an error in one of the functions: textcolour(RED);  It says that it is undefined.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
#include "Storyline.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    Storyline story;
    story.Story("Title.txt");
    textcolor(MAGENTA+BLINK);
    cout << "Hello";





    getchar();
    getchar();
    }
```

Comment: If you're using conio for that, you're probably better off using `SetConsoleTextAttribute`.

Comment: @Chris could you give me an example of SetConsoleTextAttribute.  The page im looking at for conio doesnt appear to have it.

Comment: conio is old. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686047(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Oh SetConsoleTextAttribute  is part of the windows.h library didnt know that.  Got it working cheers man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply used system("color 0a"); from the **"Windows.h"**. And i now have what i needed.